# Can't access to remote pentaho bi-server

Tags: java, tomcat, hosting, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I uploaded mi "pentaho biserver-ce-6.0.1.0-386" to my hosting and set the variables needed but i keep getting error like this:

> 04-Mar-2016 11:14:27.427 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint.findUncoveredHttpMethods
>   For security constraints with URL pattern [/jsp/*] only the HTTP
>   methods [POST GET] are covered. All other methods are uncovered.

I didn't find a guide-tutoial for biserver on a remote hosting in my pc in local is working perfectly

I modified the web.xml to my domain name, I have mi pentahoo bi-server under the directory "demo-odoo.ecommlean.com/pentaho"

eco.web08 ~ # cat /var/www/demo-odoo.ecommlean.com/htdocs/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/logs/pentaho.log
2016-03-04 11:13:21,975 INFO [org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafInstance] ******************************************************************************* *** Karaf 
Instance Number: 1 at /var/www/demo-odoo.ecommlean.com/htdocs/pen**   **taho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/karaf//data1**   **Karaf Port:8801**   
**OSGI Service Port:9050**   **JMX RMI Registry Port:11098**   **RMI Server Port:44444 *** 
******************************************************************************* 2016-03-04 11:13:29,897 INFO [org.pentaho.di] 2016/03/04 11:13:29 - cfgbuilder - 
Warning: The configuration parameter [org] is not supported by the default configuration builder for scheme: sftp 2016-03-04 11:13:40,657 ERROR 
[org.pentaho.di.osgi.KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifycycle Listener failed to execute properly. Releasing lifecycle hold, but some services may be 
unavailable. 2016-03-04 11:13:51,859 ERROR [org.apache.felix.configadmin.1.8.0] [[org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin]]Cannot use configuration 
org.pentaho.requirejs for [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=562, bundle=187/mvn:pentaho/pentaho-requirejs-osgi-manager/6.0.1.0-386]: No visibility to 
configuration bound to mvn:pentaho/pentaho-server-bundle/6.0.1.0-386

netstat -an | grep -w -e 8801 -e 9050 -e 11098 -e 44444
tcp6       0      0 :::11098                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::44444                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.1.1:44444         127.0.0.1:47797         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:47797         127.0.1.1:44444         ESTABLISHED

I attach my logs and web.xml

[logs](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/75wexsqxf0pwvlg/AABtres0rUhExhPRbU9uuY2sa?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

According to logs attached server even was not started properly since there is a lot of exceptions on port 8080 already in use.
I would try to stop server, using kill to release ports and make attempt to start again.
Make sure you are really want to start remote server on 8080 port.

Comment: I changed the port to 9999 and modified trusted ip's and fully-qualified-url , opened the port and restart the server. Now is working :9